# How to remove the Win10's PATH from WSL

Tags: linux, maven, path, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Windows Subsystem Linux(Ubuntu 18.04) in my Win10, and I install a Maven in it. 
Besides, I install a maven in Win10 before.
Now when I used `mvn compile` in WSL, it told me that maven compile fail.
I use `which mvn` and find that it references to the Maven installed in Win10.

Besides, I run `env` and find that Win10's Path is added to the WSL's Path.
I don't want to use any thing in Win10's Path when I use WSL, how should I do?

Answer (score 132):

### For Windows builds [HIGHER than 17713](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17713):

WSL uses the file [`/etc/wsl.conf`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/) inside each Linux VM's filesystem to configure its behavior. Add the following configuration settings ([explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17713)) to `/etc/wsl.conf`, creating that file if necessary:

```ini
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = false
```

Note that `appendWindowsPath` *must* be under `[interop]` for this to work. You may need to shutdown the current instance of WSL with `wsl --shutdown` or `wsl -t <Distribution>` for changes to take effect. You could also add the option `enabled = false`, also under the `[interop]` section, to disable the ability to launch Windows binaries from inside WSL.

### For Windows builds LOWER than 17713:

WSL uses [WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/wslapi/ne-wslapi-wsl_distribution_flags) to configure its behavior. Here is the code snippet from `wslapi.h` header file.

```c
/* Flags specifying WSL behavior */
typedef enum
{
  WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_NONE                  = 0x0,
  WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_ENABLE_INTEROP        = 0x1,
  WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_APPEND_NT_PATH        = 0x2,
  WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_ENABLE_DRIVE_MOUNTING = 0x4
} WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS;
        
#define WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_VALID (WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_ENABLE_INTEROP | WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_APPEND_NT_PATH | WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_ENABLE_DRIVE_MOUNTING)
#define WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_DEFAULT (WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_ENABLE_INTEROP | WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_APPEND_NT_PATH | WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_ENABLE_DRIVE_MOUNTING)
```

At first launch, WSL uses the default `flag = 0x7` (i.e. 0+1+2+4). If that `flag = 0x5` (i.e. 0+1+4), the Windows NT path will not appended in the `$PATH` environment variable. To find that flag's registry value, open `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss` in Registry Editor aka. `regedit.exe`. Open each subkey with UID values and match `DistributionName` with your installed distribution name. Then edit/add the `Flags` DWORD registry value to `0x5`.

Comment: After modifying "wsl.conf" file in WSL you need to "wsl --shutdown" for the changes to take effect.

Comment: The latter did not exactly work for me. Even though it's an ini file, I removed all the comments (after #, including #) and put spaces around '='.
To restart WSL, you can also ctrl-x->powershell(admin) and run "Restart-Service LxssManager".

Comment: This fixed my conda installation that had problems after updating my linux distribution to WSL2. Because it suddenly imported windows paths that caused unexpected errors when trying to activate conda environments.

Comment: Worth noting, if you installed WSL on Windows 10 prior to having 17713 installed, the first instructions are still the answer.

Comment: This actually worked! For me, the resolution at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1493#issuecomment-266480323 did not do anything. Adding the interop to wsl.conf worked. (I'm using WSL2 by the way)

Comment: WSL1 on Win10 LTSC 1809 Build `17763.1875`, the registry edits were required in my case.

Comment: I have (re)installed WSL/WSL2 a few times and am trying to get Ubuntu 20.04 to not use my Windows path (that has spaces in it).  I am not seeing wsl.conf; where is it located?

Comment: This no longer works as of January 2023. Had to edit the registry according to the other answer.

Comment: In my case (Windows 11 22H2), the default value for the Flags in the registry was 15 (0xf) (not sure what the extra 0x8 bit means) so I subtracted 2 from it and set it to 13 (0xd) and it worked.

Answer (score 56):

## 1st step - Disable Windows path on WSL

#### Option A: Add to wsl.conf (after Build 17093)

```
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf
```

Then add

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = false
```

then
`Ctrl+S` then `Ctrl+X` then `exit`.

#### Option B: remove paths on runtime

Add the following code to `.bashrc`

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/printenv PATH | /usr/bin/perl -ne 'print join(":", grep { !/\/mnt\/[a-z]/ } split(/:/));')
```

**Alternative (run once!):**

```
echo "export PATH=`echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | grep -v /mnt/ | tr '\n' ':'`" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Alternative 2**

Just add `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"` to the end of `~/.bashrc`, so that `usr/bin` takes precedence over windows' apps. Probably not a good option.

#### Option C:

Edit Windows Registry. *It is currently not recommended.*

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\{GUID}\Flags
```

Change `Flags` from `7` to `5` in order to exclude the `WSL_DISTRIBUTION_FLAGS_APPEND_NT_PATH` enum.

---

## 2nd step - Restart WSL

#### Option A:

Simple reenter WSL and test:

```
echo $PATH
```

#### Option B:

Run at PowerShell as Admin:

```
Restart-Service LxssManager
```

#### Option C:

Terminating WSL from PowerShell as Admin using

```
wslconfig /t Ubuntu
```

Adapt was your need, `Ubuntu-18.04` in my case

---

References:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1493

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl

https://gist.github.com/ilbunilcho/4280bd55a10cefef75e74986b6bff936

Comment: The most comprehensive answer!

Comment: While `wsl.conf` is available after Build 17093, the option `appendWindowsPath` is only available in Insider Build 17713 and later

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the `Flags` attribute in the Windows Registry still works with WSL 2. It worked fine for me and didn't cause any issues whatsoever. The only difference is that the initial `Flags` value in my case was `0x0F (= 15)`. Changing that to `0x0D (= 13)` prevents appending the Windows %PATH% to the Ubuntu $PATH.

You can still find all WSL 2 distributions in the Registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\`. Each distribution has its own GUID subfolder, looking something like

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\
    |
    |-- {40db8e6f-0520-4ddd-9c8b-0f5414e685c9}
    |-- {6a61345d-2dc6-4b9e-abb1-28a26d64e19f}
    |-- {bce2f98a-b234-4749-adbe-7311df078d26}
    |-- ...
    |-- {ea808e4e-dc24-4645-aed0-ebd67c871e01}
```

Of course, your GUIDs will be different from mine.

By clicking on each of the GUIDs and looking at the `DistributionName` attribute you can find out which GUID refers to what WSL 2 distribution, see (1) in screenshot below. And then simply modify the `Flags` value and set it to 13, see (2) in screenshot. If the value in the `Flags` attribute is different from `0x0F` it shouldn't matter, just reduce it by 2 and you should be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Warning: if your WSL2 distro was installed after Windows build 17093, do NOT change the "Flags" regedit value from 0xf to 0x5, as would be the case for WSL1. This will destroy your WSL2 setup the next time it gets shutdown/rebooted, losing all of your data. Changing it to 0xD instead will work to remove the NT path from your unix path.