# Opening the file explorer from wsl2 debian

Tags: debian, wsl-2, microsoft-file-explorer

Just upgraded to wsl2 with debian distribution and I wanted to access my files from windows, after some searching I have stumbeld over the following link:

https://www.howtogeek.com/426749/how-to-access-your-linux-wsl-files-in-windows-10/

I did as requested in this link, logged in as root, entered to the root folder and ran the following command:

> explorer.exe .

but the output was "bash: explorer.exe: command not found", it seems like it should work, I have tried it in different locations along with the mounted c drive, the regular user and so on.

My question is, why doesn't it work and how can i fix it?

with respect,
revolution

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `wsl.exe --list` from a Powershell/CMD window and get the exact name of the distro
2. Go to `\\wsl$\` in explorer and check if you see your distro name there. If not run `wsl --shutdown`, start a distro again and recheck
3. You'll see all your running distros listed, click to open it's filesystem

You can right click and map it as a network drive for easier access too

[image: Example]

Following [rixtech's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556603/13207968) works too if you're already in that folder in the terminal

Run

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/windows' >> ~/.bashrc
```

and add this to `~/.bash_aliases`

```
alias start='/mnt/c/windows/explorer.exe'
```

Comment: Generally speaking, images shouldn't be hyperlinked to a third-party application on the forum. Also could be more comprehensive on the exact steps to take? Please update your answer with the changes I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

*> why doesn't it work*

`explorer.exe` is not found in the out-of-the-box `$PATH` in WSL2 Debian.

The article at https://www.howtogeek.com/426749/how-to-access-your-linux-wsl-files-in-windows-10/ illustrates opening the File Explorer using WSL2 Ubuntu.

WSL2 Ubuntu has some magic that appends the current user's Windows `%PATH%` to the Linux `$PATH` but that doesn't appear to be the case for WSL2 Debian at this time. It seems that many folks prefer to turn that magic off, e.g. [How to remove the Win10's PATH from WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336147/how-to-remove-the-win10s-path-from-wsl)

*> how can i fix it*

Some options

- Specify the full path at the command line, e.g., `/mnt/c/windows/explorer.exe .`
- Append to the path for the current session

> ```
> PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/windows
> ```

- Append to the path for future sessions by adding to your `~/.bashrc` file, e.g.,

> ```
> echo 'PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/windows' >> ~/.bashrc
> ```

- Edit `~/.bash_aliases` and create an alias

> ```
> alias start='/mnt/c/windows/explorer.exe'
> ```

If creating an alias, you can alias to whatever you prefer, e.g. *explore* or *explorer.exe*. Personally I prefer to alias to *start* because it matches what you'd type at at CMD or PowerShell prompt, e.g. `start .` opens the current directory in File Explorer.