# Replace $PATH with string/file? Set $PATH to null and append?

Tags: bash, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Backup, first.

Before attempting to resolve this, people are worried about $PATH changes breaking things.  Backup your path with `echo $PATH > $HOME/bak/conf/path.bak` and remember (don't put any raw files into the bak dir).  C**onf**irm your backup with `cat $HOME/bak/conf/path.bak`.

### *A minimal $PATH!*

My **desired path** is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`.
This is a **minimalist path** that **should break nothing** on most default Linux installs (**Backup, first**).

I have a huge $PATH that is completely useless (like **120 lines of $PATH**--**caused by WSL** [more later]).  So far, I only know how to add to path and remove single directories from $PATH via `seg`.

Sounds like it ***should*** pop right up on search engines.  I have a headache in my eye--:
**how do I set $PATH to a raw string or purge it so I can append from null**?.

**Bonus points for anyone who can tell me how to set $PATH from the contents of a file!?**

### Best guess:

`import sys, sys.path.insert(0, '/your/path')`--!NO This did not work!

### Temporary workaround:

You can move the path to a neutral file (or use whatever means you know) and replace / with / and then use sed to cut the unwanted part out:

`PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/tons:\/of:\/unwanted:\/garbage$//')`
Make sure you put everything you don't want between s/ and `$//')`.

### Where is this long $PATH coming from?

Related question: [How to remove the Win10's PATH from WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336147/how-to-remove-the-win10s-path-from-wsl) --$PATH is inherited every time you re-launch or perform some other actions such as possibly changing users or environments.

### Why is this question different:

As if there isn't enough typing, S.O. has a nuisance dialog that asks me to write and explain why **purging $PATH is different from removing one directory/path from $PATH**.

Because a punch in the face isn't a kick in the butt.

Comment: Some concretion would perhaps be useful. A common mistake is having the same directory listed multiple times, perhaps because you ran some installer repeatedly and it added the same thing to your `.profile` or similar again and again. Knowing which directories _should_ be on your `PATH` is a great start, but your question reveals no research into this topic. In broad terms, removing multiple directories is no different from removing one directory; just loop over the ones you want to remove if that's your actual question. But fixing whatever added them there is probably a better approach.

Comment: @tripleee Than you for your comment: yes, I agree--there are some s.o. articles about removing duplicates: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40749/remove-duplicate-path-entries-with-awk-command might be useful for that case.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I do understand that you could write a loop or copy-and-paste and then add a bunch of \'s to a `seg` command; however, it is **significantly faster to purge $PATH**, and re-set it by writing the 2 or 3 necessary directories for a minimalist $PATH--especially for people without pastebins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, you simply want to know how to set your Bash `PATH` to a fixed string (or erase it completely) and have it persist across restarts of the shell?

If so, then I'll start off by saying that this isn't recommended as it *will* break other things.  If not now, then later.

But if you really want to set the `PATH` to a fixed value every time Bash starts ...

*Short answer first:*

Assuming fairly "default" startup files (where `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc`):

- Edit your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` in the rare case it exists) and add:

  ```
  # Remove entirely
  unset PATH
  export -n PATH

  # Optionally
  export PATH=/new/pathItem1:/new/path/Item2
  ```

  Adding this to the *bottom* of the file should override any other `PATH` modifications done previously.  However, future application installations can make modifications *below* that, therefore overriding it.
- In a very rare case where you have an interactive Bash session that isn't startup by a login shell, you could also make the same modifications to `~/.bashrc`.
- (Not necessarily required if the modification is the *last* thing called during startup, but) make sure that there are no other `PATH` adjustments in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

*More explanation:*

> Where is this long $PATH coming from?

Your path in Bash in WSL can potentially come from a few sources:

- WSL's `init` process sets a default `PATH` for the starting application (shell).  This is currently (in WSL 0.70.8):

  > `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib`

  Since this is done before your `~/.profile` runs, there's no need to worry about disabling it.
- As you've pointed out, WSL automatically appends the *Windows* path to the Linux path so that you can launch Windows executables.  This can be disabled using the method in the question you linked, but it's not necessary if you simply want to *override* the entire `PATH`.  Setting the `PATH` in your `~/.profile` comes *after* WSL sets it for the initial process (your shell).
- Bash itself has a built-in, default path that is hardcoded into it for "fallback" in case no other path is passed in.  This *rarely* ever takes effect.  Most Linux systems are going to set the `PATH` through some other mechanism, meaning the fallback never gets activated.  A typical Linux system will set the default `PATH` via `/etc/environment`, but this isn't used under WSL since the `init` mechanism mentioned above is needed instead.
- If using Systemd or another init system in WSL, then Bash (and other POSIX shells) will process `/etc/profile` and files in `/etc/profile.d` when starting.  These files may contain `PATH` modifications.  Again, since these come *before* your `~/.profile`, (re)setting the `PATH` to a fixed value will override any of these settings.
- Finally, your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` (for login shells) and `~/.bashrc` (for interactive shells are read.  Typically, `PATH` modifications in these files look something like:

  ```
  export PATH="/new/path/item:$PATH"
  ```

  This *prepends* to the path, making that new item take priority over the previous items.

  However, leaving out the existing `:$PATH` part will simply set it to a string literal.

It should be obvious, but if you do this without including the "normal" OS paths, you will be unable to call any command that isn't built in to Bash already with specifying its fully qualified path.  For instance, `ls` will fail.  Note that you can still:

```
$ ls
ls: command not found
$ /usr/bin/ls
# works
```

Also note that `~/.profile` is called for *login* shells.  It is possible, however, to tell WSL to launch Bash without reading `~/.profile`:

```
wsl ~ -e bash --noprofile
```

The resulting shell will still have the *default* WSL path in this case.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I wanted to do: you read my question perfectly, and I really appreciate it.  Thank you for your response: this answer is perfect for my case, and now I don't need to add \'s before all the /'s via some external text editor--huge time saver!  Thank you so much, @NotTheDr01ds.