WSL picking up windows path when using CMake
I installed googletest in WSL. I copied the gtest static libraries to /usr/lib. And then moved gtest and gmock folders to /usr/local/include/.
I wrote a simple program for gtest and it worked using the command :
g++ -o exec main.cpp -lgtest -lpthread

But when I try with CMake and make I get errors. What I noticed is that cmake is fetching the windows path.
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
message("GTest_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${GTest_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(my_executable main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(my_executable ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)

Fetching path from Windows in CMakeCache.txt
//The directory containing a CMake configuration file for GTest.
GTest_DIR:PATH=/mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/cmake/GTest

Errors that I get :
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/libgtest.dll:(.idata+0xc34): multiple definition of `__imp__ZTVNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'; /mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/bin/libgtest.dll:(.idata+0xc34): first defined here

main.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'


How are you running CMake? Are you running it from your linux OS?

The PATH variable in WSL distros tends to have Windows paths in them from the get-go. Some useful information for this question would be the output of echo $PATH. A manual install of gtest also sounds like a disaster. A package manager would be so much better.

@drescherjm WSL with Ubuntu 22.04.3

@sweenish thanks for the clue! I just removed the windows paths from WSL and it worked!

The Windows paths in WSL were interfering with GTest.
I just disabled the Windows path and it started working fine.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345880/8551671
